# Get MainWindow Instance WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, program-entry-point, mainwindow

I have some custom extensions, which when i double-click on it, it launch program and every time as i do it, it creates new mainwindow. So i want not create, but update the first mainwindow. I searced many articles, but don't find a way how to do it.

Now my code looks like this. I do it in App.xaml.cs with Startup event

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
         

            Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            // Find the main window associated with the current process
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentProcess.ProcessName);
            Process mainWindow = processes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero);

           
           

            if (e.Args.Length == 1)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.Args[0]);
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.Args[0]);
                filepathforwindow = file;

                if (mainWindow != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IntPtr mainWindowHandle = mainWindow.MainWindowHandle;
                        MessageBox.Show(mainWindowHandle.ToString());
                        HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(mainWindowHandle);
                        MainWindow mainW = hwndSource.RootVisual as MainWindow;


                        // Find the MainWindow by matching the handles

                        MessageBox.Show(mainW == null? "0": "1");

                        if (mainW != null)
                        {

                            // Now you have the MainWindow instance
                            // You can access its properties or methods
                            mainW.Load_From_File(file);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                    

                }

             
            }
          
        }
```

I tried MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType().FirstOrDefault();, also tried get it by process. Process is active, what's good, but mainWindow always null

Comment: If you start a new process, it can't just go grab something out another process.

Comment: yeah, i understand it, but how do i achieve it? i mean i can get  proccess of first mainwindow and prevent creating a new one mainwindow, but idk how to get reference to it and use method and etc

Comment: Why do you need go this way? You can creat simple client/server application or use shared memory for interprocess communication.

Comment: "Interprocess-Communciation" and "Single-Instance app" would be the key words.

Comment: yes, i'm working wiith Memory-Mapped Files after your words, but i can't get how i should read it, i mean how did this i mainwindow

Comment: could you please explan how do i notify the current process? i want notify mainwindow.xaml.cs process from app.xaml.cs before shutdown, if it's a second instance

Comment: Why are you starting a new process at all? Why not just interact with the one you've got?

Comment: @Andy well, how I understand everytime I use associated file for program it creates a new process, so i want to control this process (pass the filepath from it and shutdown after it), but it's other question i guess

Comment: Think of your app as being in two pieces. There's the startup part and the showing stuff part. When you start up you can use some communication mechanism to see if your app is already running. If it is then tell that instance via a message what the showing part should do. Then close your second instance. Or alternatively, just tell your first instance to close and show stuff in your new one. Depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: At present though, the lack of explanation of end purpose means there could be no definitive answer and your question seems unsuitable for SO. I suggest you clarify your purpose sufficiently that someone could provide a definitive answer.

Comment: i created new question where i described what i want to get
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983449/singleinstance-wpf-project