# SingleInstance WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, mutex, ipc

I have extensions files (.cogu, .cogd) that when I double-click on it, they open program. So, i want prevent creating multiple windows and work in single one, also if second instance has a path to file pass this to the first instance. I research through many articles, but mostly they're depend on WinForms, but I need exactly WPF.

Only that I have now is only detecting second instance by using Mutex.

```
        Mutex myMutex;

 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            bool aIsNewInstance = false;
            myMutex = new Mutex(true, "MyWPFApplication", out aIsNewInstance);
            if (!aIsNewInstance)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already an instance is running...");
                App.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
```

My question is: how do i pass second instance args to first instance and work with them?
P.s: I already viewed all arcticles on StackOverflow about Singleton, no one helped me

Comment: Copy of a comment on your previous question: *"Interprocess communication" and "single-instance app" would be the key words.* That is what you should be looking for. The second instance would pass its arguments via some kind of IPC mechanism to the first instance, then terminate.

Comment: yes, I understand, but it's hard for me to operate with them. If I'm not mistake, there is some methods like memory-mapped files, socket, pepi (?) connection,  but I can't get how I should operate with them to get data in first instance (MainWindow)

Comment: You would obviously have to make yourself familiar with how these mechanisms work. There are books and a lot of online information.

Comment: Yeah, you're right and i should get to know how to make it work in my case, huh :D
But I appreciate any help, so thanks!

Comment: Maybe this helps getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15133791/1136211. Your first task would be to read a bit about a few different technologies, then decide which to try first, then try something. You could learn how sockets work, which is generally useful knowledge.

Comment: managed to do it with this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224031/Passing-Parameters-to-a-Running-Application-in-WPF
thank for help